# Approaching Hard Surface Model

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, bevel

I'm attempting to model this weapon from Apex Legends. Some parts of it I have successfully modelled, such as the magazine, however, I'm pretty stumped on with the main body. I've tried subsruf modelling it but the edge loops always mess up the curved surfaces. Any help on how to approach this is greatly appreciated.[image]

[image]